# Use of \readrecordarray with macro arguments

Tags: arguments, readarray

I'm trying to use [`readarray` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/readarray) to load several multi-line files with `\readrecordarray` command for the next processing. Due to processing of several files `\readrecordarray` is used in a command with a name of macro to store the values as an argument. So instead of `\readrecordarray{file.in}\someNewMacro` I need to use `\csname` in some way to define macro "`\csname #1\endcsname`" to store all values.
From the package sources I understand that `\readrecordarray` for the second argument, e.g. `\someNewMacro` is trying to cut off the first symbol '`\`' and define the corresponding macro but still can't make it in a proper way. Copying with `\LetLtxMacro` from a temporary macro also didn't help because that temporary macro is overwritten with each new file.

Is there any way to use `\readrecordarray` with macro arguments (e.g.#1) (according to the source code below)?
Thanks!

```
\newcommand\readrecordarray[2]{%
\edef\@arrayident{\rdar@macroname#2}%
\def\ra@TermA{\@readdef{#1}}%
\def\ra@TermB{\expandafter\ra@TermA\csname\@arrayident def\endcsname}%
\expandafter\ra@TermB\expandafter{\@arrayident}%
}
\def\rdar@macroname{\expandafter\@gobble\string}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit?  Are you trying to use `\readrecordarray` with a `\someNewMacro` specified as `\csname someNewMacro\endcsname`?

Answer (score 0):

It is not wholly clear what you are requesting.  But, if I understood the gist, you need the array into which `\readrecordarray` parses the file contents to be specified by way of a `\csname` variable.

In the MWE below, I show the process if the array is specifed in the standard way, and then I show it again, in which the array is specified by way of a cs specification.  In both cases, the file is read and the 3rd array element (3rd line of the file) is detokenized to the output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{readarray}
\begin{document}
Note: junk.tex is the name of this source code file.

\readrecordarray{junk.tex}\arrayA
\arraytomacro\arrayA[3]\tmp
\detokenize\expandafter{\tmp}

\def\snippet{\readrecordarray{junk.tex}}
\expandafter\snippet\csname arrayB\endcsname
\arraytomacro\arrayB[3]\tmp
\detokenize\expandafter{\tmp}
\end{document}
```

[image]